# Browser screen pixels - css

Tags: css

When i try to see the layout in firebug it shows the body pixel as 1614*931 but my windows screen resolution in settings shows 1366*938. How to change the pixel value of the html body using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css px measurement is not necessarily equal to a pixel. I would recommend using percentage to make it the same distance in all laptops.